# How can I use the lemma for Arabic word without diacritics in stanfordrdnlp python package?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, arabic

I applied tokenization and lemmatization in an arabic sentence using the stanford-nlp Python package and the result is as follows:

text: العراق    lemma: عِرَاق
text: بلد   lemma: بَلَد
text: رائع  lemma: رَائِع

How can I remove the diacritics from the words?

Answer (score 1):

It's late, but I hope this answer can still help others facing this issue

You can use the [**hazm**](https://github.com/roshan-research/hazm) library to do this in Python:

```
pip install hazm
from hazm import *

text = "عِرَاق بَلَد رَائِع"
cleaned = Normalizer().remove_diacritics(text)
print(cleaned)
# عراق بلد رائع
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/doc/segmenter/README-Arabic.txt):

> Blockquote
>   ArabicTokenizer supports various orthographic normalization options that can be configured
>   in ArabicSegmenter using the -orthoOptions flag. The argument to -orthoOptions is a comma-separated list of
>   normalization options. The following options are supported:
>
> ...
>
> removeDiacritics  : Strip all diacritics
>
> removeTatweel     : Strip tatweel elongation character
>
> removeQuranChars  : Remove diacritics that appear in the Quran
>
> ...

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex will solve your problem.

Try to following code to remove Arabic diacritics:

```py
import re


lemma = 'رَائِع'
lemma_without_diacritics = re.sub(r'[\u064b-\u065f]', '', lemma)
print(lemma_without_diacritics)  # output: رائع
```

`[\u064b-\u065f]` represents the standard Arabic diacritics range.

Refer to [Arabic Character Code Tables](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) for more info.